# Using an external filter with tablesorter when using ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, filtering, server-side, tablesorter

Is there a way with tablesorter to use a dropdown filter external to the table when using ajax that filters based on criteria not related to a column in the table?

For instance, if the table is a list of accounts, i'd like to be able to filter on expired accounts even if that is not one of the columns in the table. Each of the columns in the table will also have their own standard tablesorter filters.

Since I'm using ajax and server-side filtering, even the column filters are just used to send a `$_REQUEST` to the ajax url and not filtering what is showing in the table. So I'd like to be able to send such a `$_REQUEST` without having to associate `filter_formatter` with a specific column.

I realize I can do this by adding a dummy column, use `filter_formatter`, and bind the external dropdown through a change function similar to the example shown at [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/abkNM/11/), but I was hoping there was a simpler way.
Thanks

Comment: I would think you could use the `filtering_function` method but create a dropdown, instead of buttons. I don't think you're going to find an "easy way out" on this one. The `tablesorter` plugin is nice but it could sure use some more development.

Comment: Fair enough - thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the [customAjaxUrl](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/#pager-customajaxurl) option. Within that callback code, you can get the currently selected external filter and append it as a string which is sent to your server. Something like this:

```
// modify the url after all processing has been applied
customAjaxUrl: function(table, url) {
    // get current selection & add it to the url
    return url += '&filter=' + $('.external-filter').val();
}
```

---

To answer your question from the comments, you can try binding to the change event of the external filter, then save that filter value into the table data (if you don't want to use a scoped/global variable). Try something like this:

```
$('.external-filter').on('change', function(){
    $('table')
        .data('filter_value', $(this).val() )
        .trigger('update');
});
```

then within the `customAjaxUrl` function do this:

```
// modify the url after all processing has been applied
customAjaxUrl: function(table, url) {
    // get current selection & add it to the url
    return url += '&filter=' + $(table).data('filter_value');
}
```

Comment: Thanks Mottie, but when a dropdown value is selected in the external filter, it doesn't trigger a tablesorter ajax call since it's outside the table. How do I get the external dropdown to trigger the ajax call?

Comment: Try triggering an [update](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/#update) on the table `$('table').trigger('update');` or maybe even use the pager [`pageSet`](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/#pageset) or [`pageSize`](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/#pagesize) methods.

Comment: Okay - using `update` but when I get to `customAjaxUrl` I can no longer see which external filter triggered the update (I have more than one sometimes) unless I set a global variable. Just checking if there's a way within tablesorter to pass the id of the selector from `update` to `customAjaxUrl`. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks so much Mottie. Sorry you're having to teach me basic jQuery!

Comment: An update to this with version 2.13.3. Replaced the above solution (which had stopped working) with method shown [here](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-widget-filter-any-match.html), which is simpler. In particular, used this code:      `$(".search").bind('search keyup', function (e) {
    $('table').trigger('search', [ [this.value] ]);});`